# Deploying a Precompile build for .NetCore 3.1 visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, web-deployment, iis-express, .net-core-3.1

I want to deploy a pre-compile build on IIS in order to improve performance of the application. I found one solution on this link,
https://forums.asp.net/t/2156430.aspx?How+to+precompile+in+VS+2019

But I am not having "Precompile during publishing" option in my visual studio. I have different options, see in the image.[image]

Note: I have also deploy build by enabling "Enable ReadyToRun Compilation". but it does not make any affect in performance.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What I have come to know, in .NetCore views are by default precompiled not like MVC 5.